# How to set expiry for Zeebe Workflow Instance

Tags: camunda, zeebe

Is there an option to set an expiry time while initiating a workflow instance in Zeebe?

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate a bit on this? What do you want to achieve? You could use an timer start event with an event sub process.

Answer (score 0):

Since you question is a bit vague I can just guess what you want to achieve. What you could do is to use an event subprocess with an interrupting timer start event. This will completely interrupt your workflow instance after the time is due. You can then do some clean up tasks or what ever you want.

More information about event subprocess in Zeebe you can find in the [documentation](https://docs.zeebe.io/bpmn-workflows/event-subprocesses/event-subprocesses.html).

[image]